# How to Install Google Chrome from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome

I'd like to do something similar to:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**except download the OS X version** (from ? URL) and install it from the command line. The corresponding instructions for installing Google Chrome on Ubuntu can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line). I've searched high and low and Google does not seem to make the link available anywhere.

I'm trying to write a script to automate installation of my standard applications for OS X. I use a set of scripts like this already to set up my Ubuntu box. Specifically, I can't seem to find the URL for the Google Chrome OS X 64 bit direct download.

---

**Edit, final solution:**

```
wget https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg
open ~/Downloads/googlechrome.dmg
sudo cp -r /Volumes/Google\ Chrome/Google\ Chrome.app /Applications/
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this after mucking around with the page source:

https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg

Comment: At which point they could `open /path/to/googlechrome.dmg` and `cp /volume/googlechrome/Google\ Chrome.app /Applications/`

Answer (score 11):

I have used a script like this to copy applications from disk images:

```
temp=$TMPDIR$(uuidgen)
mkdir -p $temp/mount
curl https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg > $temp/1.dmg
yes | hdiutil attach -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint $temp/mount $temp/1.dmg
cp -r $temp/mount/*.app /Applications
hdiutil detach $temp/mount
rm -r $temp
```

- Without `-mountpoint` the dmg is mounted to a directory like `/Volume/Google\ Chrome/`.
- `-nobrowse` doesn't show the volume in Finder.
- If the dmg has a license agreement, `yes |` skips it.
- cp preserves extended attributes (which includes resource forks) and ACLs by default. As far as I know, ditto is no longer needed for copying application bundles.

Or using [brew-cask](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask):

```
brew install brew-cask
brew cask install google-chrome
```

brew-cask installs applications to `/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/` and creates aliases to `~/Applications/` by default.

Comment: +1 for the mention of brew-cask which seems very useful for improving Homebrew.

Answer (score 8):

**edit 2022:** `brew install` can now do casks by default

```sh
brew install google-chrome
```

(Thanks to wisbucky for bringing it up in a comment below)

**edit 2019:** homebrew has a new syntax for casks:

```sh
brew install --cask google-chrome
```

**original:**
`brew cask install google-chrome` also works if you have homebrew.

(It basically does the same thing as your final solution)

Comment: "if you have homebrew", but do I need also `brew-cask` (brew install brew-cask)

Comment: "To start using Homebrew Cask, you just need Homebrew installed." source: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#lets-try-it

Comment: Now, you don't even need the `--cask`. Simply `brew install google-chrome` will work. (Verified on Homebrew 3.3)

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in being able to download any of their branches. If you look at the `https://www.google.com/chrome/assets/common/js/chrome-installer.min.js` file, you'll see the links you need. Here is an excerpt.

```
Pn(a,"win64")?"/update2/installers/ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe":"/update2/installers/ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe":"/update2/installers/ChromeSetup.exe";else if(Wn(a))if(a.sb)a="/chrome/mac/beta/GoogleChrome.dmg";else if(a.ta)a="/release2/q/canary/googlechrome.dmg";else if(a.Sa)a="/chrome/mac/dev/GoogleChrome.dmg";else{a="GGRO";var b=new Y(location.href),b=qk(b,"brand");if(b=b.length&&b[0])for(var c=0,d=Gn.length;c<d;c++){var f=Gn[c],h=f.ki;if(f.Vj.test(b)){a=h;break}}a=pa("/chrome/mac/stable/%s/googlechrome.dmg",a)}else a=Xn(a)?An[a.Bj+(a.sb?"-b":a.Sa?"-d":"")]:"/update2/installers/ChromeSetup.exe";return a}e.Rr=function(a){this.sm=a};
```

As you can see from doing a simple search on the minified code above, you'll find the last half of the links that should be concatenated with https://dl.google.com/chrome/

Answer (score 0):

Because at the first install you don't have wget or brew, you can use curl, this works for me:

```
curl https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg --output googlechrome.dmg
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to download it for Macs using Intel or Apple Chips.

```
        if
            [[ `arch` == arm64 ]]; then
            echo "Architecture is Apple ARM"
            curl https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/universal/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg --output googlechrome.dmg
        else
            echo "Architecture is Intel X86"
            curl https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg --output googlechrome.dmg
        fi
```

Answer (score -1):

The way to install Google Chrome will be to download & install it manually through click and install. Download appropriate Google Chrome Deb package. Then sudo dpkg -i  .
...
Add the key.
Set Repository.
Update package.
Install chrome.