# How to reinstall chrome-browser on OSx via Terminal?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, chromium

My chrome-browser seems to be corrupt, crashing frequently.

**How can I clean the place and reinstall it via the terminal ?** It first need to clean the place, then [to install chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/602680/) again.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Chrome folder at ~/Library/Application Support/Google 
Quick way... switch to Finder. Cmd/n for new window, then Cmd/shift/g for Go. Copy/paste the above path including the tilde ~

Then drag Chrome to the trash. Then install again.
No Terminal needed.